# how to set 2 objects in one group in javafx

Tags: object, javafx, position, z-order

I dont know how to discribe this Problem.
I want to set a Textobject in the middle of a cell (gridpane) with a rectangle in the background.  Dont know how to do this or search for the right word for this problem. Hope someone will help me. :-)

Thats my code for now:

```
void AbtButton(String Abteil) {

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

    r.setWidth(80);
    r.setHeight(40);
    r.setArcWidth(20);
    r.setArcHeight(20);
    r.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
    r.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    r.setStrokeWidth(2);;
    r.toBack();

    Text abt = new Text(Abteil);
    abt.setId(Abteil);
    abt.setFont(Font.font ("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
    abt.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    abt.toFront();

    Button.getChildren().addAll(r,abt); 
  }
```

if I make

```
gridpane.add(r, 1, 1);
gridpane.add(abt, 1, 1);
```

it shows me the correct picture and fills the cell with the rectangle and the text is in the center position.

with

```
Button.getChildren().addAll(r,abt);
```

the Textobject is on the wrong position namely above the rectantangle and that shouldn't be, but i need this. later i want to create a lot of this grouped objects.

toBack() and toFront() doesn't work here too :-(

edit:

here i have a picture of the Problem.

http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3449/blgrlw63_jpg.htm

The z-order of the text should be in front and the rectangle in back in this gridpane.
With this code

```
abt.setLayoutX(27);
abt.setLayoutY(27);
```

it is possible to set the Position of the text but is not a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `StackPane` class to solve your problem. Have a look at the following code:

```
 GridPane g1 = new GridPane();

    StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    r.setFill(Color.AQUA);
    Text t = new Text("StackOverFlow");

    sp.getChildren().addAll(r,t);

    g1.add(sp, 0, 0);

    Scene sc = new Scene(g1,200,200);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.show();
```

The stackpane works in the "last in -- first out" way. So your last added child is the first to display (or better: the element on top of the pane). Any following children will be placed behind the first child.

To solve your problem, create a stackpane, then put the rectangle in it, and then the text. After that, put the stackpane in the desired position on the gridpane.

Comment: yes, i also thought to use stackpane but i couldn't realize it, but with this example it is possible! thx ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Hbox instead of Rectangle because there is no property to set text into Rectangle shape.

```
    gridFirst.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    hboxFirst.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
    hboxFirst.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hboxFirst.getChildren().add(new Text("hello"));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah, that is also a good solution, I will experiment with it :)